# How to generate a table of names based on complicated criteria in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Screenshot:

[image: Table of Month & Item Availability]

Hi experts,

I am trying to make a table in Excel that can generate a "Doc #" for each day of the month (for Monday to Friday only) based on availability. I've included a template for the month of October and a table for each "Doc #" availability. Please see the image I have attached.

I had thought that I can do this in Excel but I'm currently stumped. is there a way for Excel to generate a "Doc #" (A to H) based on their availability on that day. It was be as evenly distributed as possible.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Your description isn't clear. Can you post what the outcome would look like?

Answer (score 0):

That is a request for code, IMO.

Here is a "deduced" answer... something for you to ponder on.

Enter a date in A1, then place this in A2:
`=TEXT($A$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&CHAR(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$1)+64)`
... and optionally copy it into at most 25 more rows below.